# Send emails using Nodemailer from gmail

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I want the website to send an email everytime I access "/email". (I did say yes to accept allow less secure apps to access account setting in my google account) However, it never actually sends me an email, but gives me an error instead.

```
{ Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d51sm16118087qtd.35 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1509:34)
    at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:547:26)
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:933:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:739:14)
    at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/Users/jenniferzhou/Documents/2018 - 2019/CS5150/Bethe-OPS-Project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:691:47)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response:
   '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d51sm16118087qtd.35 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

This is my code below. Can anyone please help?

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'senderemail',
        pass: 'passwordtosenderemail'
    }
});

const mailOptions = {
    from: 'betheops@gmail.com',
    to: 'emailreceiver@email.com',
    subject: 'This is a test email',
    html: '<p>This is a test</p>'
};

app.get('/email', function(req, res) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        else
            console.log(info);
    });
})
```

Comment: The [docs](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) state: 'When using this method make sure to also enable the required functionality by completing the ["Captcha Enable”](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/displayunlockcaptcha) challenge.' Did you do that?

Comment: yes I did but it still does not work